# Create a blur like windows 7 taskbar with css?

Tags: javascript, css

How can a blur like in the windows 7 taskbar created with css or js.

Comment: can you add pic to clarify the question

Comment: Here's a link that might help: http://blog.vervestudios.co/blog/post/2011/04/15/Applying-Gaussian-Blur-to-HTML-elements-with-CSS.aspx

Comment: Here's a good cross-browser link about opacity: http://www.itnewb.com/tutorial/Cross-Browser-CSS-Opacity-and-the-JavaScript-Fade-Fading-Effect

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS3 transitions, opacity, rgba colors etc. Use linear gradients as a background image.

Comment: I almost want to ask you how you would use transitions, opacity, RGBA and linear gradients to achieve such an effect, but I think I'll watch the question get closed instead.

Comment: Uh, I'm not sure what he means with "blur effect in the taskbar". I guess mine looks different from his...